# How do I round values in a column based on integers in another column

Tags: python, rounding

I need to round prices in a column to different number of decimals in Python. I am using this code to create the dataframe, df_prices:

```
    df_prices = pd.DataFrame({'InstrumentID':['001','002','003','004','005','006'], 'Price':[12.44,6.5673,23.999,56.88,4333.22,27.8901],'RequiredDecimals':[2,0,1,2,0,3]})
```

The data looks like this:

```
InstrumentID    Price      RequiredDecimals  
1              12.444     2  
2              6.5673     0  
3              23.999     1  
4              56.88      2  
5              4333.22    0  
6              27.8901    3
```

I often get this issue returned:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Neither of these statements worked:

```
    df_prices['PriceRnd'] = np.round(df_prices['Price'] , df_prices['RequiredDecimals'])

    df_prices['PriceRnd'] = df_prices['Price'].round(decimals = df_prices['RequiredDecimals'] )
```

This is what the final output should look like:

```
Instrument#    Price      RequiredDecimals     PriceRnd  
1              12.444     2                    12.44  
2              6.5673     0                    7  
3              23.999     1                    24.0  
4              56.88      2                    56.88  
5              4333.22    0                    4333   
6              27.8901    3                    27.890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a better solution, but this one seems to work

```py
df['Rnd'] = [np.around(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['Price'],df['RequiredDecimals'])]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked the first time. The values in 'Price' was rounded to different number of decimals.

Comment: am i doing something wrong here? I tried your code and it returned 2dp for all the values.

Comment: @Axois `[np.around(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['Price'],df['RequiredDecimals'])]` gave me an output as follows: `[12.44, 7.0, 24.0, 56.88, 4333.0, 27.89]`

Comment: @Axois `np.around(6.5673, 0)` would still give me `7.0`, not `7` as in your example.

Comment: @Axois what I thought was the case - OP wants to use `pd.Series.round` function on a column, using values from another column as decimal values. if that's the case, my solution works as expected.

Comment: @Axois if I'm mistaken, OP should definitely un-accept my answer

Comment: @politicalscientist Im just finding it odd that the values that are being outputted for me is `[12.44 7.00 24.00 56.88 4333.00 27.89]`.

Answer (score 1):

Although not elegant, you can try this.

```
import pandas as pd
df_prices = pd.DataFrame({'InstrumentID':['001','002','003','004','005','006'], 'Price':[12.44,6.5673,23.999,56.88,4333.22,27.8901],'RequiredDecimals':[2,0,1,2,0,3]})
print(df_prices)
list1 = []
for i in df_prices.values:
    list1.append('{:.{}f}' .format(i[1], i[2]))
print(list1)
df_prices["Rounded Price"] =list1
print(df_prices)

  InstrumentID      Price  RequiredDecimals Rounded Price
0          001    12.4400                 2         12.44
1          002     6.5673                 0             7
2          003    23.9990                 1          24.0
3          004    56.8800                 2         56.88
4          005  4333.2200                 0          4333
5          006    27.8901                 3        27.890
```

or a 1-liner code

```
df_prices['Rnd'] = ['{:.{}f}' .format(x, y) for x,y inzip(df_prices['Price'],df_prices['RequiredDecimals'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to adjust the number that you are trying to round with an appropriate factor and then use the fact that the .round()-function always rounds to the nearest integer.
`df_prices['factor'] = 10**df_prices['RequiredDecimals']
df_prices['rounded'] = (df_prices['Price'] * df_prices['factor']).round() /  df_prices['factor']`
After rounding, the number is divided again by the factor.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using the pandas round function on the series by exploiting transpositions.

You can do this:

```
df_prices[['Price']].T.round(df_prices.RequiredDecimals.to_dict()).T
```